# Accessing DOM elements is not always working - jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to execute code that accesses elements in the page.

My HTML code looks like below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.6/handlebars.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="app.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container">
        <input type="text" id="user" /> 
        <input type="button" id="add" value="add"/>
        <ul id="peopleList">
        </ul>
        <script type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="template">
        {{#each people}}
        <li>{{.}}</li>
        {{/each}}
        </script>
     </div>
</body>
```

My JavaScript code looks like below:

```
    (function(){
  var people = {
    people: ["first", "second"], 
    init: function(){
      this.cacheDOM();
      this.render();
    },
    cacheDOM: function(){
      this.$dm = $("#container"); 
      this.$userField = this.$dm.find('#user');
      this.$submitButton = this.$dm.find('#add');
      this.template = this.$dm.find("#template").html();
      this.$peopleList = this.$dm.find("#peopleList");
    },
    render: function(){
      var compiled = Handlebars.compile(this.template);
      this.$peopleList.html(compiled(this.people));
    },
  };

  people.init();
})();
```

During the execution, it seems like I don't have access to the DOM elements, as they are undefined, although I have taken this code from this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m-NYyst_tiY&list=PLoYCgNOIyGABs-wDaaxChu82q_xQgUb4f&index=2

In the video, he's not using $(document).ready, but still he's able to access DOM elements right away, why am I having a different behavior?

Comment: Because the guy in the video placed his javascript files further down the DOM, after the html elements. This way, the DOM is already loaded by the time the javascript gets executed.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. Thank you. Add it as an answer so I can close it

Comment: You're welcome. Posted it as answer as you requested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the guy in the video placed his javascript files further down the DOM, after the html elements. This way, the DOM is already loaded by the time the javascript gets executed.

Comment: A better answer would point out that jQuery offers a `ready()` method which only fires once the DOM has been loaded and is safe to manipulate. See [https://api.jquery.com/ready/](https://api.jquery.com/ready/) for the official documentation.

Comment: Not sure that'd make the answer any better, as the question already includes this info. The real question is about how the person in the video is able to access the DOM without it.

Comment: Fair enough, answer upvoted. Though I would always recommend using the `ready()` method so that the code ordering does not cause these problems.